# Django Connect to remote database using ssh and pem file

Tags: django, django-settings

I can access database by SSH to some aws instance using pem file.

How do i connect the django to that postgres database.

Django Database connect has sslkey etc in options. But couldn't find the ssh tunnel option.

Any pointers pls

Update:- Due to Company policies can’t change the settings like white list up etc . In aws cloud no issues as all are white listed . I wanted to connect local Django setup to staging / uat database for testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options

You can either create an ssh tunnel to map the remote server to a local port

```
ssh -L <local port>:127.0.0.1:<remote port> <username>@<remote host> -N
```

Whiles this process is active the local port will connect to the remote port on the remote host. You can something like `supervisord` plus a script to make sure the ssh connection launches before your app.

Another option would be [django-db-tunnel](https://github.com/mvx24/django-dbtunnel)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have same issue with https://www.pythonanywhere.com postgres database. but it's working with SSH tunnel

```
ssh -L <local port>:127.0.0.1:<remote port> <username>@<remote host>
```

Example to connect pythonanywhere.com postgres database using SSH tunnel

```
ssh -4 -L 5432:xxxxxx.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com:12499 <db_name>@ssh.pythonanywhere.com
```

After SSH connection you can point django postgres port to local port